# onehalfspacing in titlepage

Tags: titles, line-spacing

How to make onehalfspacing in titlepage? I tried to add `\onehalfspacing` command in different places there, however, no spaces were produced.

```
\begin{titlepage}
{\fontsize{22}{22}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipisicing elit}} 
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: You might want to add a paragraph break (`\par`) at the end of the group. Also the second number of `\fontsize` is the baselineskip, i.e. the line spacing, which is normally 20% larger than the font size (the first number). So use `{\fontsize{22}{27}\centering ... \par}`. The 27 should probably be even higher. I wouldn't recommend to use `\fontsize` at all, but `\Huge` and the `setspace` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the brackets around your sentence:

```
\documentclass[pagesize]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\onehalfspacing

\fontsize{22}{22}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As stated above `\fontsize{22}{22}` isn't right and might interfere with `setspace`. The second number should be at least 20% higher.

Comment: @Keks Dose Thanks. It really works but I have another problem now. I want to write some not bolded text after this and \bfseries without brackets around makes not a good job. I cannot change it to \textbf because of \MakeUppercase. How should I solve this?

Comment: @myname: Try it with the braces but with a `\par` before `}`.

Comment: @myname If possible and if it seems adequate to you, please hit the "answer accepted" button on the left side of my answer.